# Python switch case with dic and function calls for cases

Tags: python

i tried to implement a Turing Machine in Python. I wanted to make transition between states with switch case. But in switch case i confronted the difficulty to break after a case.

```
 def transition(self,current_state):
    switcher = {
         0 :self.start(),
         1 :self.suche0(),
         2 :self.suche1(),
         3 :self.Test0(),
         4 :self.Test1(),
         5 :self.Rewind()
     }
```

I defined a function for each case but when i running it once the programm goes into multiple cases. Is there a possibility to break after the programm was in one case?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the call to function. If you are using `()`, you are calling the functions at the declaration of `switcher` itself.

```
def transition(self,current_state):
    switcher = {
         0 :self.start,
         1 :self.suche0,
         2 :self.suche1,
         3 :self.Test0,
         4 :self.Test1,
         5 :self.Rewind
     }
```

..and use them as, for ex:

```
switcher[2]()
```

..which calls `suche1`.